# When mongodb server is down how to catch the error while running mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose for connecting node.js with mongoDB, now i wrote below query

```
var trans = new transmodel({method: method, trans_id: r});
  trans.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
            console.error("Razor_pay_webhook Error 4 err: " + err);
            res.write('statusCode: 200');
            res.end();
     } else {
        res.write('statusCode: 400');
        res.end();
     }
  });
```

I thought when my mongodb cluster will be down then i will get 'err' while executing above mongoose query, but when i ran above query while my mongo cluster was down nothing happened(No err was called). Can anyone please tell me **how can i catch the error if my mongodb server is down inside my query**. Also for reconnecting again with my cluster i have set below parameters but my node server is not trying to reconnect again with my mongodb server i don't know what's going wrong.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var config = require('./config/database.js');
    var DB_URL = config.db.url;

    mongoose.connection.on("connected", function(ref) {
        console.log("Connected to " + " DB!");
    });

    mongoose.connection.on("error", function(err) {
        console.error('Failed to connect to DB ' + ' on startup ', err);
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function(err) {
        console.log('Mongoose default connection to DB :' + ' disconnected');
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    });

    var gracefulExit = function() { 
        mongoose.connection.close(function () {
            console.log('Mongoose default connection with DB :'  + ' is disconnected through app termination');
            process.exit(0);
        });
    }

    process.on('SIGINT', gracefulExit).on('SIGTERM', gracefulExit);

    exports.con_close = function () {
        console.log('Mongoose connection disconnected');
        mongoose.connection.close();
    }

    var options = {
        server: {
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1000,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000
            }
        },
        replset: { 
            rs_name: 'replicaset',
            auto_reconnect:true,
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1000, // doubt about it
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000
            } 
        },
        user: 'root',
        pass: 'G3saGT2Y',
        auth: {
            authdb: 'admin'
        }
    }

    mongoose.connect(DB_URL, options, function(err) {
        console.log('ho rha hai');
        if (err) {
            console.log('error connection to mongo server!');
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does your application start to hang - not responding to requests?

Answer (score 3):

You are using mongoose, it emits events (the EventEmitter pattern) when the database is down and when the database is reconnecting and up again.

from mongoose code found [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) we can see that the library db connection - [connection.js](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/a8038eb9718a57c07a563368ae52d0af31944f33/lib/connection.js)

has the following events that are emitted:
 * @param {Mongoose} base a mongoose instance 
 * @inherits NodeJS EventEmitter

http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter
 * @event `connecting`: Emitted when `connection.{open,openSet}()` is executed on this connection.

- @event `connected`: Emitted when this connection successfully connects to the db. May be emitted *multiple* times in `reconnected` scenarios.
- @event `open`: Emitted after we `connected` and `onOpen` is executed on all of this connections models.
- @event `disconnecting`: Emitted when `connection.close()` was executed.
- @event `disconnected`: Emitted after getting disconnected from the db.
- @event `close`: Emitted after we `disconnected` and `onClose` executed on all of this connections models.
- @event `reconnected`: Emitted after we `connected` and subsequently `disconnected`, followed by successfully another successfull connection.
- @event `error`: Emitted when an error occurs on this connection.
- @event `fullsetup`: Emitted in a replica-set scenario, when primary and at 
  least one seconaries specified in the connection string are connected.
- @event `all`: Emitted in a replica-set scenario, when all nodes specified in the connection string are connected.

When the database is down you will receive two events:
1. disconnected 
2. error (the error that driver encountered)

When the database is up again you will receive the reconnect event.

So you don't need to try catch the error rather you should listen to these events.

More helpful information about connection failures and reconnecting can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connection_failures/).

This article explain how to use and configure the autoReconnect and the bufferMaxEntries according to your settings.